# Can Exchange emails be downloaded in Apple Mail to then be uploaded to Gmail account?

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail, exchange

I use Apple Mail and I have a work account on Exchange/Office 365 that I use through Apple Mail. I do NOT have the Exchange password, I am not the administrator. Is there a way for me to archive or download all the emails (to a .OLM or .PST file?) and then import them to a Gmail account?

Bottom Line: I want my Exchange emails exported to a Gmail account.
Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Note: I tried to do this by setting up a rule to forward all of my Exchange emails to the Gmail account...but after a short time it keeps crashing the Apple Mail application.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't own the account login details, you've picked the best solution, this would be to set up a rule forwarding all **new** emails to your Gmail email.

Any Mail Client, including Apple Mail, app needs log credentials to establish the connection. So to be able to use Gmail as client app for your Exchange account, you will either have

- to submit those manually  or
- to have the password in [iCloud
  keychain](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204085)

For the older emails, you can export them in .pst and upload that to Gmail but that's rather desktop operation. I think [this](http://www.blog.edbtopst.org/how-to-transfer-exchange-server-emails-into-gmail-account.html) should help.

Comment: How do i convert all of the emails I have archived into a .pst file so I can upload them to gmail?